# How do I affect another view's property when ImageView is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView inside a LinearLayout view. I want to change the color of the LinearLayout view while the ImageView is pressed.

I know I can swap out the ImageView image when the state changes through drawables, but I cannot seem to find the ideal way to affect another view in the layout while isPressed is true on this specific image view.

Ultimately, I am trying to create a bottom ActionBar and simulate the regular ActionBar highlight box (that is, when you press a menu item in the ActionBar you get the highlight box). Right now I have the ImageView a LinearLayout with a small (8dp) padding on the top and bottom. I can replace the image in the ImageView with one that has a 50% white background, but I cannot do it this way if I want to keep the images device density independent. Instead, I'd like to have a square layout the button exists in that I would change the color of as needed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"I have an ImageView inside a LinearLayout view. I want to change the color of the LinearLayout view while the ImageView is pressed."

for this : 
you define your ImageView in XML as clickable `android:clickable="true"`
you affect an OnClickListener to this ImageView in your Activity onCreat() :

```
ImageView yourImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image);
yourImage.setClickable(true); // if you want to define it here
yourImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout).setBackgroundColor(your_color);
            }
        });
```

Else if you want to change the color only when it is clicked and restore the old color after the click, you can implement OnTouchListener :

```
yourImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
            // when the click begins
            findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout).setBackgroundColor(your_click_color);
            return true;
        } else {
           // when the click finishs
           findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout).setBackgroundColor(your_init_color);
          return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

});
```

I hope I helped...